# Extrude face with Python

Tags: python, add-on

I want to extrude a face in the direction of the face normal, here is the code so far:

```
r = bmesh.ops.extrude_face_region(bm, geom=bm.faces[:])
verts = [e for e in r['geom'] if isinstance(e, bmesh.types.BMVert)]
bmesh.ops.translate(bm, vec=dir, verts=verts)
```

The problem is how to get the direction of the face that I translate? The bm.faces[0].normal is Vector(0,0,0)

Any ideas? Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update the normals**

Either update normals on a whole bmesh

```
bm.normal_update()
```

or on a per face basis

```
for f in bm.faces:
    if sometest:
        f.normal_update()
```

Comment: Yeah, thx, I also found it, I use the normal_update on the frist face, cause I am sure that there is at least one.